# Saving a file with umlauts on a CentOS machine

Tags: php, file-upload, unicode, character-encoding, filenames

We have a CentOS 6 machine with an Apache webserver that accepts file uploads from a rich Javascript client. The files are saved with php's `move_uploaded_file`

The client and the server (php) files are all encoded in iso-8859-1, and the database on the server as well. Also, the html output declares iso-8859-1 as charset.

File uploading works fine so far, except files with umlauts (or other yet unknown special characters) result in an error. For example, the file `1.Nachtrag Gemeinde Höchst.pdf` gets echoed correctly in the application, and also the link which is produced to download the file has the correct (url-)encoding:

```
http://ourdomain/saba/data/dok/00000092/1.Nachtrag%20Gemeinde%20H%C3%B6chst.pdf
```

But when clicking on this link, a 404 error appears. When looking for the file in the shell, it gets displayed as `1.Nachtrag Gemeinde H?chst.pdf`, which indicates some sort of wrong encoding, although it might be just because the shell has a utf-8 encoding.

What did we forget?

Comment: I think you answered your own question. `iconv` to UTF-8, or normalise to ASCII.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Amadan has correctly pointed out, the filename needed to be converted to utf-8 before saving, i.e.:

```
 $filename = iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $filename);
 $is_successful = @move_uploaded_file($tmp_filename, $ordnername . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);
```